# Alamofire Paramaters not Serialising Properly

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, alamofire

So I have never had this issue when using `AFNetworking` or any other API call using `Alamofire` however I seem to be having an issue, basically I have an `Array of Dictionaries` which should be formatted like this;

```
[{"value":"1","created_at":"2018-06-26 01:57:14"},
 {"value":"4","created_at":"2018-06-26 01:59:44"}]
```

However they are coming through server side like this;

```
[{"value":"4"},{"created_at":"2018-06-26 02:30:11"},
{"value":"4"},{"created_at":"2018-06-26 03:24:41"}]
```

I tried creating hard coded parameter to get it to work but no success, where am I going wrong guys (I know it's probably something stupid),
here is the hardcoded demo parameters;

```
let dictA =  ["value":"2", "created_at":"2018-06-26 04:05:50"]
let dictB =  ["value":"4", "created_at":"2018-06-26 05:05:50"]
let params : NSDictionary = ["values":[dictA,dictB]]
```

tia

//EDIT

Here is the `Alamofire` request;

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in 
    //Handle response 
})
```

//EDIT

I have solved it with a work around, for some reason the objects format properly when they are serialized into the body using a native `URLRequest` first then initialising the `Alamofire` request using that request;

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
         //Handle response
})
```

Comment: Does your server is under your control? If not you can't map your response as you xpected.

Comment: Can you share your hole code to get and parse your data?

Comment: As I stated in the question, that is the hardcoded parameters and that is exactly how it's sending using Alamofire; 

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
   //Handle response
})

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
let params: Parameters = ["values": [dictA, dictB]]
```

or

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["values": [dictA, dictB]]
```